# how to check in java that input is an integer and is in certain range by using hasNextInt()

Tags: java

I want a user to enter a number which is an `int` and is between 1 and 8. I want to keep prompting the user until the number is between 1 and 8 and it is an integer.

What I've tried:

```
System.out.println("Enter number between 1 and 8");
while(!console.hasNextInt())
{
    System.out.println("not valid try again between 1-8");
    console.next();

}
int number = console.nextInt();

while (number < 1 || number > 8)
{
     System.out.println("number is not between 1 and 8 try again ");
     number = console.nextInt(); // the problem is here because user might enter string or double.

}
```

how can I make my program more robust?

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? What do you want to do when the user enters a double? Also, please check this condition: `while (number < 1 && number > 8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like:

```
int number;
System.out.println("enter a number between 1 and 8");
do {
      while (!console.hasNextInt()) {
            console.nextLine(); // consume input
            System.out.println("not an integer. try again");
      }

      number = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());
      if(number < 1 || number > 8)
          System.out.println("number is not between 1 and 8 try again ");

} while (number < 1 || number > 8);
// do something with number
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I shoudld have used OR operation. I want user enter number between 1 and 8 and be integer. and if it is not between 1 and 8 and if it is not integer, it keep asking until user input satisfy criteria. for what you wrote if user enter double or string it does not go into loop. How can I modify it if it is necessary. sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!